# StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB on startActivity with JSoup (Android 6.0)

Tags: android, jsoup, stack-overflow, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have not received this crash report in my Play Console, but I am getting it when testing the app in Android Studio. I have a "news" button that takes the user to an Activity that uses JSoup to grab news links from a website. As soon as the button is pressed, it begins to create the Activity and crashes immediately. I don't use finish() with the previous activity so they can go right back to what they were doing when they're done.

Here is the Click Listener in MainActivity:

```
newsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsActivity.class);
                startActivity(newsIntent);
            }
        });
```

Here is my NewsActivity:

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mListView;
    Document document;
    Elements newsTitles;
    Elements newsLinks;
    static Elements dates;
    static Element date;
    Elements datesStrings;
    static Element link;
    static String href;

    private static final String TAG = "NewsActivity";
    private ArrayList<Article> mArticleList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        HtmlParser htmlThread = new HtmlParser();
        htmlThread.execute();

        mListView = findViewById(R.id.articleListView);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Article a = mArticleList.get(position);
                href = a.getHref();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(href);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public class HtmlParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, ArrayList<Article>> {
        private static final int NETWORK_NO_ERROR = -1;
        private static final int NETWORK_HOST_UNREACHABLE = 1;
        private static final int NETWORK_NO_ACCESS_TO_INTERNET = 2;
        private static final int NETWORK_TIME_OUT = 3;

        Integer serverError = NETWORK_NO_ERROR;

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this, R.style.CustomSpinnerStyle);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setMessage("Getting Your News!");
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Article> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                //get the web document
                document = Jsoup.connect("<URL HERE>").get();

                //get titles
                newsTitles = document.getElementsByClass("<SOME CSS CLASS HERE>");
                //get newsLinks
                newsLinks = newsTitles.select("a[href]");

                //get the dates class
                dates = document.getElementsByClass("<SOME CSS CLASS HERE>");
                //get the date text
                datesStrings = dates.select("time");

                for(int i = 5; i < newsLinks.size() && i < datesStrings.size(); i++) {
                    link = newsLinks.get(i);
                    date = datesStrings.get(i - 5);
                    mArticleList.add(new Article(link.text(), link.attr("href"), date.text()));
                }
                return mArticleList;
            } catch(ConnectException e) {
                serverError = NETWORK_NO_ACCESS_TO_INTERNET;
                return null;
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                serverError = NETWORK_HOST_UNREACHABLE;
                return null;
            } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
                serverError = NETWORK_TIME_OUT;
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        } //end doInBackground
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        } // end onProgressUpdate
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Article> result) {
            if(result != null) {
                ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.articleListView);
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(NewsActivity.this, R.layout.custom_textview, mArticleList));

                if(dialog.isShowing()) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            } else {
                switch(serverError) {
                    case NETWORK_NO_ERROR:
                        Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Oops. Invalid response from server.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_NO_ACCESS_TO_INTERNET:
                        Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "No Internet connection found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_TIME_OUT:
                    case NETWORK_HOST_UNREACHABLE:
                        Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Error in connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnec
```

Again, this only happens when using Android 6.0 as my Emulator, and I have not received a crash report from my Play Console. Is this a setting in Android Studio I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, sorry for wasting your time. I disabled "Advanced Profiling" by going to Run -> Edit Configurations -> Profiling -> Uncheck "Enable advanced profiling." This is not an issue out in the wild, so it was because of my own settings.

Comment: You didn't waste my time. You actually provided a helpful clue to a similar issue I'm facing. Except that in my Android Studio (2021.3) there is **no** `Enable advanced profiling` checkbox. Any idea where to find it?

Comment: I haven't developed on Android in several years, but I did some googling and found this in their docs. Will it help you? 

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler